# MS Access [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid cursor state

Tags: sql, ms-access

I had the error in this code snippet:

```
   private String[][] connectToDB(String query) throws ClassNotFoundException{
        String[][] results = null;
        try {

                Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                String db = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=E:/EACA_AgroVentures1.accdb";
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(db);
                stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);

                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
                ResultSetMetaData rsm = rs.getMetaData();
                rs.beforeFirst();
                int columns = rsm.getColumnCount();
                int rows = getRowCount(rs);
                //int rows = rs.getFetchSize();

                int rowCount = 0;
                results = new String[rows][columns];
                //System.out.println(rows+" "+columns);
                while((rs!=null) && (rs.next())){                    
                     for(int i = 1; i < columns; i++){
                        results[rowCount][i-1] = rs.getString(i); // --> ERROR SHOWS HERE
                        //System.out.println(rowCount+","+i+" = "+rs.getString(i));
                     }
                     rowCount++;
                }
                rs.getStatement().close();
                conn.close();

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        return results;
    }
```

My query consists of the following:

```
private void loadMR(){
      try {
            String query = "SELECT dealerCode, SUM(kg) AS totalKG, SUM(price) AS totalPrice, returnDate, BID FROM meatReturns GROUP BY BID, dealerCode, returnDate;";            
                Object[][] result = connectToDB(query);

// some more code below..
```

I tried using the first code with some other query given in another method:

```
private void loadDealers(){
        try {
            String query = "SELECT * FROM Dealers";            
            Object[][] result = connectToDBWithRows(

query);
// some more code..
```

and it runs perfectly well. What is going on here? How can i fix this problem?

UPDATE: the only difference of connectToDBWithRows and connectToDB is the while loop that manages the `resultSet`

```
// Snippet from connectToDBWithRows()
while((rs!=null) && (rs.next())){

                    for(int i = 0; i < columns; i++){
                        if (i == 0){
                           // Do nothing
                        }else{
                           results[rowCount][i] = rs.getString(i);
                           //System.out.println(rowCount+","+i+" = "+rs.getString(i)); 
                        }
                    }
                    rowCount++;
                }
```

and this is my `getRowCount()` method

```
  private int getRowCount(ResultSet resultSet){
        int size = 0;
        try {
            resultSet.last();
            size = resultSet.getRow();
            resultSet.beforeFirst();
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            return 0;
        }
        return size;
    }
```

Comment: Its a method I made. It uses the `resultSet` to return the number of rows, I'll update my post.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that sometimes, Access needs you to specify the table name when referring to columns in sql statements. Try the following:

```
private void loadMR(){
      try {
            String query = "SELECT meatReturns.dealerCode, SUM(meatReturns.kg) AS totalKG, SUM(meatReturns.price) AS totalPrice, meatReturns.returnDate, meatReturns.BID FROM meatReturns GROUP BY meatReturns.BID, meatReturns.dealerCode, meatReturns.returnDate";
                Object[][] result = connectToDBWithRows(query);
```

Comment: I tried this solution but the problem still persists :(

Comment: i changed my code to `connectToDBWithRows` instead of `connectToDB`. Does that work?

Comment: oh the `connectToDBWithRows` is pretty much the same with `connectToDB`, ill update my post.